# How does the Firewind Blade's bonus stack?

Tags: dnd-4e

The Firewind Blade's property states,
"Whenever you hit one or more targets with a fire power using this weapon, one enemy adjacent to you takes fire damage equal to 1+the weapon's enchantment bonus."
How often does this damage activate? If I use a close blast power that hits three targets, would the damage instance occur once for each target, or once total for the power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would only trigger once. This is because the trigger is written "one or more" and 3 is one or more. If it had instead been "Whenever you hit a target" it would indeed trigger 3 times.

Comment: There are absolutely people on the charOp boards who disagree with diego here, but even there, they're in the minority. The clear intent is 1/power. In any discussion of the Firewind Blade, it's important to note that it's a separate damage instance, which potentially pings vulnerabilities twice.